# For Loop Vectorization - elementwise

Tags: python, for-loop, data-structures, vectorization

I have a problem with vectorizing a for loop for the following dummy scenario.

```
a = [i+2 for i in range(5)]
b = [i**2 for i in range(5)]
c = list(range(3,8))

answer = 0

for i in range(1, 1+c):
    answer += a**i +b**i
```

Obviously, the above form doesn't work since range doesn't take list as an input.
For each element in c I want to do the following operation. IE for the 0th index

```
answer = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
for j in range(c[0]):
    answer[0] += a[0] **j + b[0]**j
```

I'm not sure what the best approach would be. The additional problem (which is why I've been thinking) is that a,b,c could individually be a float or an iterable data structure. I hope this is enough information, I simplified it because the actual variables a,b,c and the for loop logic is a bit more complicated than as shown.

Comment: The inner expression is simply `a**j + b**j`.  Now, do I gather that you want to perform this sum for every `j` in the vector `c`?

Comment: Yup! Would you say I would have to do something like:
```
[a[i] **j + b[i] **j for j in range(c[0]) for i in range(len(a))]
```

My only concern is that not all these variables may be indexable at any given point in time - would I just have to try/except it in this case?

Comment: Almost ... `for j in c` is what I *think* you want: you intend to use the values in `c`, rather than all values 0...c[0], right?

Comment: ```
[a[i] **j + b[i] **j for j in range(c[i]) for i in range(len(a))]

```

I believe this is what I want if I could index all of them - but I am relying on broadcasting when say one of the elements ends up just being a float (sorry I should have used a np.array rather than lists for the arrays). 

Also it should be a cumulative sum on j (which I didn't end up doing above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i have understood the question correctly, then the following will work.

```
for ind, j in enumerate(c): # enumerate return a tuple of index and value at that index, ind, j
    answer += (a[ind] ** j) + (b[ind] ** j)
```

We can "Pythonize" it and create an iterator in the same way.

```
answer = sum([(a[ind] ** j) + (b[ind] ** j) for ind, j in enumerate(c)])
```

[EDITED] to fit OP'S new problem:

```
#  Same concept as above

for ind, j in enumerate(c):
    answer[ind] += (a[ind] ** j) + (b[ind] ** j)
```

Iterator version

```
answer= [(a[ind] ** j) + (b[ind] ** j) for ind, j in enumerate(c)]
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about enumerate- I think I can reach a solution with it. I mis-represented what I wanted by accident and have updated it accordingly. I didn't want a total cumulative sum but just along the c-axis. I've updated the question accordingly.